# How to read large size tab separated multiple files in R exe using SLURM?

Tags: r, tabs, large-files, slurm, sbatch

I'm attempting to write a function that reads several tab-separated files (thousands) in SLURM via sbatch using R exe code, does some tasks, and then outputs tab-separated files. The program works effectively with files smaller than 2 GB but fails to execute when the file size exceeds 2 GB. However, when I try to run those large files individually by calling R function in R shell, it works fine, albeit slowly. What I need to know is how to read large tab-separated files in R that should run through SLURM's sbatch command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla

# name: frag2bed.ex.R
#
# input: tsv formatted frag file
# output: tsv formatted bed file with chr, start, end, count as columns
# note: we expect input to be in order of input , output

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
input_file<- args[1]
output_file<- args[2]
  
  #reading frag.tsv file into R dataframe
  
    frag <- read.table(input_file,
                       header = FALSE, 
                       sep="\t",
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                       quote="")

---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------

       write.table(xyz, paste0(output_file), row.names = F, col.names   = F, sep="\t", quote=FALSE)
```

By this code the smaller size file reading very well but issue arises when using the large size data.

So, this is a humble request if anyone kindly suggest potential way to proceed will be an immense assistance for me.

Comment: To speed up the reading in, you could use `fread` from `data.table`. However, I guess that you just don't have enough memory at the SLURM node to run too many jobs in parallel. What errors do you get/how is it failing exactly? How many jobs do you start in parallel? How much memory does the node have? You could monitor the resources with `top`.

Comment: Thank you very much; I've just raised the memory in the SLURM script from 16 to 50 GB. I believe it is now working.